# Using iPod touch as microphone

Tags: ipod-touch, microphone

I have an iPod touch, and I can use the voice memo app. I don't have a mic for my PC however, and would like to use the iPod touch to record things on the PC, as well as use it for chat programs on the PC.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Anything's possible, but this isn't very probable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. There is no direct official way from Apple. I have created apps using the iPhone SDK and I can tell you there are no frameworks to do this either. Maybe there is some solution if you jailbreak it but I couldn't fine one.

Honestly, PC microphones are like $5, just buy one and save yourself the frustration this will bring.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to if you download a microphone app(usually free) and if you use a double ended jack cable that you plug from the ipod to the microphone slot on your pc

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just download a app called 'Megaphone' from the appstore  (for your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch 4th generation) and get a audio to audio cable and plug the one end into your iPhone, iPod or iPad and the other end into your computers audio jack. Then you are ready to talk.

Answer (score 1):

First if you are recording for a video or something start voice memo and play at the same time (do your commentary), then send your memo to your email (`Share -> E-mail -> To:Yourself`), then use video editing software and put your video in and use the memo as a soundtrack

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to record things but its long

1. record the memo on the app
2. press share
3. type in your email in the message
4. send the email
5. on your pc open your emails. the file will be in m4a format
6. open the file (it will open and play in itunes

if you want it as an mp3 then at step 6 save the file to your pc
and then convert it with converting softtware

unfortunately i dont know a way to use it for chat programs

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Marcin, you may as well just get a microphone...

But if you are persistent in using your iPod, there is a quick and easy way:

1. Plug one end of a 3.5mm audio cable into your computer, and the other end into your iPod.
2. Get the **Megaphone Free** app and turn it on. Tap the Microphone to turn it on and off.

***For Megaphone Free, Go To:***    itunes.apple.com/us/app/megaphone-free/id304955183

That's it! Open a recording program or something of the like on your computer, and your iPod will work as a fully-functional microphone!

---

**If you don't have an Audio Cable, you can get one for $2.17 from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SE6IV8) or for $2.28 on [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5mm-AUX-AUXILIARY-CORD-Male-to-Male-Stereo-Audio-Cable-for-PC-iPod-MP3-CAR-/330915777316?pt=US_Audio_Cables_Adapters&hash=item4d0c1e0b24).**

*If it isn't working:*

- *Make sure the volume is up.*
- *The mic is on when the speaker icon DOES NOT have waves. An OFF mic has waves.*
- *If the mic has NO waves, and it still isn't working, try recording WITH waves.*

---

If you have any further questions, please free to ask.

---